# Load images only on wi-fi?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, images, 3g

Can I somehow tell my phone to load images in (for example) browsers, gmail, twitter, etc. only when connected through a wi-fi connection? Mobile internet is pretty expensive in my country so I don't want images to spend more bandwidth than needed.. Or do I have to manualy turn it off for each app I'm using at the moment?

if it means anything, I'm using android2.2

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently no way to set a system-wide policy for this.  Some apps do support doing things on WiFi only, however.  Here's some info on the apps you mentioned:

1. You can go into the browser settings and uncheck Load Images.
2. GMail does not load images unless you view a message and click a button to display them.
3. I believe the Touiteur Twitter client allows you to disable images.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this could be done with Tasker but it would be a very long and complex setup (actually several) and you'd need to know the specific intents that turn the images off in each application.

Comment: Tasker are one thing, but unless the app developer has gone through the trouble of writing all the code to disable images but are too lazy to code the setting page themselves, it is not useful in this case.

Comment: True, but considering that he was looking for a solution as an alternative to doing in manually in each app (as he said..."Or do I have to manualy turn it off for each app I'm using at the moment?"), I think that's implied.  As far as I know, Tasker is the only alternative to doing it manually so I'm not sure why my answer deserves a downvote.